Want to detect all the words in the string
So ive written a code which would detect all the words that are there in a sentence. I would only detect the words and would ignore the spaces, which means even if there are empty spaces in the string i would not count them. But the result are not what i expected. Here is the code :


var mystring = "Hello World"
var indexcount = 0
var words = 0

for (element of mystring) {
  if (element == " " || element[indexcount + 1] != " " || element[indexcount - 1] != " ") {
    var words = words + 1
    var indexcount = indexcount + 1
  } else {
    indexcount = indexcount + 1
  }
}

console.log(words);



So this code would actually help anyone who would want to know all the words that are there in a string, ignoring all the spaces. So even if you had just a single word within a string and a lot of spaces still, the result would be 1. But i am getting weird ouputs. please help

What are you trying to achieve with the element[indexcount + 1] != " " checks?

added explanation to my answer

str.split(" ").filter(x => !!x)

You have several errors:

Don't use var after the first use on a variable
When the element isn't a space, check whether it's
a. a first element in a string (indexcount === 0)
b. or the previous character is a space (mystring[index - 1] === ' ')
If so increase the word count



var mystring = "Hello World"
var indexcount = 0
var words = 0

for (var element of mystring) {
  if (element !== " " && (indexcount === 0 || mystring[indexcount - 1] === " ")) {
    words = words + 1;
  }
  indexcount = indexcount + 1;
}

console.log(words);



Consider using a state machine:


var mystring = ` Hello 
                 World `;

const spaces = new Set('\t\r\n '.split('')); // detect spaces with a set
let words = 0;
let inWord = false; //whether we are inside of a word or not

for(const char of mystring){
  if(spaces.has(char)){
    inWord = false;
  } else if(!inWord) {
    words++; 
    inWord = true;
  }
}
   
console.log(words);



You could also use a regex:


var mystring = ` Hello 
                 World `;

const words = mystring.match(/(?<=\s|^)(?=\S)/g).length;
   
console.log(words);




Here is the Solution that you can try
function countWords(str) {
  // Split the string into an array of words using the split() method
  const words = str.split(" ");

  // Filter out empty strings (extra spaces) using filter()
  const filteredWords = words.filter(word => word.trim() !== "");

  // Return the length of the filtered array (number of words)
  return filteredWords.length;
}

// Example usage
const myString = "Hello                    ";
const wordCount = countWords(myString);

console.log("Number of words:", wordCount); // Output: Number of words: 1


Thanks for this code, but I would have liked to know why my code isn't working

Try using this function:
const countWords = (str) => {
  return str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' ').length
}

